# Bitonic Tour algorithm

Tags: python, graph, traveling-salesman

This is my implementation of [Bitonic Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_tour) (simplification of the Traveling Salesman Problem). Tests are not done very well, but it is not the point.

I would be particularly interested in the comments on architecture and performance.

**NEW VERSION**

```
import math
# see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_tour for the statement of the problem

# this class contains all distances between vertices
class Vertice(object):
    def __init__(self, vertice_coordinates):

        self.__vertice_coordinates = vertice_coordinates 
        # avoid altering input
        self.sorted_to_original_absciss_indices = range(len(vertice_coordinates))
        self.sorted_to_original_absciss_indices.sort(key = lambda index_:vertice_coordinates[index_][0])

        self.original_to_sorted_absciss_indices = range(len(vertice_coordinates))
        self.original_to_sorted_absciss_indices.sort(key = lambda index_:self.sorted_to_original_absciss_indices[index_])

        # precompute neighbouring distances
        self.distances_neighbours = [self.get_distance(self.sorted_to_original_absciss_indices[i], 
                                                       self.sorted_to_original_absciss_indices[i+1]) 
                                                                        for i in xrange(len(vertice_coordinates)-1)]

    def get_distance(self, ind_original_1, ind_original_2):
        return math.sqrt((self.__vertice_coordinates[ind_original_1][0] - self.__vertice_coordinates[ind_original_2][0])**2 + 
                         (self.__vertice_coordinates[ind_original_1][1] - self.__vertice_coordinates[ind_original_2][1])**2)

    # given an index in the original array, find next to the right and output it and the distance between the two   
    def find_next_to_the_right_and_distance(self, ind_original):
        ind_sorted = self.original_to_sorted_absciss_indices[ind_original]
        ind_original_next = self.sorted_to_original_absciss_indices[ind_sorted + 1]
        return self.distances_neighbours[ind_sorted], ind_original_next

    def get_first_node_TwoPartialPaths(self):
        ind_leftmost = self.sorted_to_original_absciss_indices[0]
        return TwoPartialPaths(path_to_rightmost = [ind_leftmost], 
                               distance_to_rightmost = 0., 
                               path_to_another_extreme = [ind_leftmost], 
                               distance_to_another_extreme = 0.,
                               vertice = self)

# this class contains information about two partial paths. 
# For each path, it know the sequence of vertices and total length
# It stores an instance of distances to avoid passing it as a parameter
class TwoPartialPaths(object):
    def __init__(self, path_to_rightmost, distance_to_rightmost, 
                       path_to_another_extreme, distance_to_another_extreme, vertice):
        self.path_to_rightmost = path_to_rightmost
        self.distance_to_rightmost = distance_to_rightmost
        self.path_to_another_extreme = path_to_another_extreme
        self.distance_to_another_extreme = distance_to_another_extreme
        self.vertice = vertice

    def __str__(self):
        result = "path 1 is {}\ndistance 1 is {}\npath 2 is {}\ndistance 2 is {}\noverall distance is {}".\
            format(self.path_to_rightmost, self.distance_to_rightmost, self.path_to_another_extreme,
                   self.distance_to_another_extreme, self.get_total_distance())
        return result

    def add_to_rightmost(self):
        additional_distance, next_vertex = self.vertice.find_next_to_the_right_and_distance(self.path_to_rightmost[-1])
        result = TwoPartialPaths(path_to_rightmost = self.path_to_rightmost + [next_vertex],
                                 distance_to_rightmost = self.distance_to_rightmost + additional_distance,
                                 path_to_another_extreme = self.path_to_another_extreme,
                                 distance_to_another_extreme = self.distance_to_another_extreme,
                                 vertice = self.vertice)
        return result

    def add_to_another(self):
        _, next_vertex = self.vertice.find_next_to_the_right_and_distance(self.path_to_rightmost[-1])
        another_extreme = self.path_to_another_extreme[-1]
        another_distance = self.vertice.get_distance(another_extreme, next_vertex)
        result = TwoPartialPaths(path_to_rightmost = self.path_to_another_extreme + [next_vertex],
                                 distance_to_rightmost = self.distance_to_another_extreme 
                                                        + another_distance ,
                                 path_to_another_extreme = self.path_to_rightmost,
                                 distance_to_another_extreme = self.distance_to_rightmost,
                                 vertice = self.vertice)
        return result

    def add_to_both(self):
        additional_distance, next_vertex = self.vertice.find_next_to_the_right_and_distance(self.path_to_rightmost[-1])
        another_extreme = self.path_to_another_extreme[-1]
        another_distance = self.vertice.get_distance(another_extreme, next_vertex)
        result = TwoPartialPaths(path_to_rightmost = self.path_to_another_extreme + [next_vertex],
                                 distance_to_rightmost = self.distance_to_another_extreme 
                                    + another_distance,
                                 path_to_another_extreme = self.path_to_rightmost + [next_vertex],
                                 distance_to_another_extreme = self.distance_to_rightmost + additional_distance,
                                 vertice = self.vertice)
        return result

    def get_total_distance(self):
        return self.distance_to_rightmost + self.distance_to_another_extreme

# solve it
def find_bitonic_path(vertice_coordinates):    
    # initialise the distances
    vertice = Vertice(vertice_coordinates = vertice_coordinates)  

    # initialisation for 2 leftmost vertice
    leftmode_vertex_node = vertice.get_first_node_TwoPartialPaths() # only leftmost vertex node
    shortest_paths_given_ends = [leftmode_vertex_node.add_to_rightmost()] # add second leftmost        

    # do other vertice, except the last one
    for _ in xrange(len(vertice_coordinates) - 3):
        # find the last element, when we add to another extreme
        best_last = shortest_paths_given_ends[0].add_to_another()
        for pspge in shortest_paths_given_ends[1:]:
            challenger = pspge.add_to_another()
            if challenger.get_total_distance() < best_last.get_total_distance():
                best_last = challenger 
        # handle simple cases, when we add to the rightmost extreme,
        # and the other extreme does not change
        shortest_paths_given_ends = [
            spge.add_to_rightmost() for spge in shortest_paths_given_ends] + [best_last]

    # do the rightmost vertex
    result = shortest_paths_given_ends[0].add_to_both()    
    for spge in shortest_paths_given_ends[1:]:
        challenger = spge.add_to_both()
        if challenger.get_total_distance() < result.get_total_distance():
            result = challenger

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    vertice_coordinates = [[3,4], [7,0], [10,4], [0,0], [1.5,2]] # [(random.random(), random.random()) for _ in xrange(4)]
    for v in vertice_coordinates:
        print v
    result = find_bitonic_path(vertice_coordinates = vertice_coordinates)
    print result
```

**RESPONSE TO SUNNY'S COMMENTS**

- I assume that the code is part of larger library, therefore 1. I do not alter the input because the user does not necessarily expect it 2. I output the results in terms of the input, i.e. number of a point is the same as in the input.
- I am using dynamic programming. For each point, I compute a set of optimal partial paths that include this point and all points to the left of it. That is, at each iteration I find all optimal subpaths with the end points \$(P_0, P_n), (P_1, P_n), ... (P_{n-1}, P_n)\$ given optimal subpaths with the end points \$(P_0, P_{n-1}), (P_1, P_{n-1}), ... (P_{n-2}, P_{n-1})\$. Finding optimal subpaths \$(P_0, P_n), (P_1, P_n), ... (P_{n-2}, P_n)\$ is trivial: we add edge \$(P_{n-1}, P_n)\$ to \$(P_0, P_{n-1}), (P_1, P_{n-1}), ... (P_{n-2}, P_{n-1})\$. Finding optimal subpaths that end with \$P_{n-1}\$ and \$P_{n}\$ is slightly trickier, as you add an edge to "another extreme", so you need to compare \$(P_0, P_{n-1}) + (P_0,P_n), (P_1, P_{n-1}) + (P_1,P_n), ... (P_{n-2}, P_{n-1}) + (P_{n-2},P_n)\$ to find the shortest \$(P_{n-1},P_n)\$.
- `distance_to_rightmost` and `distance_to_another_extremum` correspond, more or less, to the lengths of *top* subpath and *bottom* subpath, because, ultimately, each subpath goes towards the rightmost point. More exact name for the first distance will be `distance_to_rightmost_point_included_so_far`, but it is I think it is too long.
- adding `result` variable is terribly helpful when you debug, I believe it is a common practice
- I called a class `Vertice` because it contains all points (vertice) as opposed to just one point (vertex).
- I agree that nested calls are not good, I will change that!

**ORIGINAL VERSION**

```
import math
# see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_tour for the statement of the problem

# this class contains all distances between vertices
class Distances:
    def __init__(self, vertice): 
        # avoid altering input
        sorted_indices = range(len(vertice))
        sorted_indices.sort(key = lambda index_:vertice[index_][0])
        self.__distances = [[math.sqrt((vertice[i][0]-vertice[j][0])**2 + (vertice[i][1]-vertice[j][1])**2)
                                                for i in sorted_indices] for j in sorted_indices]

    def get_(self, vertice_1, vertice_2):
        return self.__distances[vertice_1][vertice_2]

# this class contains information about two partial paths. 
# For each path, it know the sequence of vertices and total length
# It stores an instance of distances to avoid passing it as a parameter
class TwoPartialPaths:
    def __init__(self, path_to_rightmost, distance_to_rightmost, 
                       path_to_another_extreme, distance_to_another_extreme, distances):
        self.path_to_rightmost = path_to_rightmost
        self.distance_to_rightmost = distance_to_rightmost
        self.path_to_another_extreme = path_to_another_extreme
        self.distance_to_another_extreme = distance_to_another_extreme
        self.distances = distances

    def print_out(self):
        print "path 1 is", self.path_to_rightmost
        print "distance 1 is", self.distance_to_rightmost
        print "path 2 is", self.path_to_another_extreme
        print "distance 2 is", self.distance_to_another_extreme
        print "overall distance", self.get_total_distance()

    def add_to_rightmost(self):
        new_vertex = self.path_to_rightmost[-1] + 1
        result = TwoPartialPaths(path_to_rightmost = self.path_to_rightmost + [new_vertex],
                                 distance_to_rightmost = self.distance_to_rightmost 
                                                        + self.distances.get_(new_vertex, new_vertex-1),
                                 path_to_another_extreme = self.path_to_another_extreme,
                                 distance_to_another_extreme = self.distance_to_another_extreme,
                                 distances = self.distances)
        return result

    def add_to_another(self):
        new_vertex = self.path_to_rightmost[-1] + 1
        another_extreme = self.path_to_another_extreme[-1]
        result = TwoPartialPaths(path_to_rightmost = self.path_to_another_extreme + [new_vertex],
                                 distance_to_rightmost = self.distance_to_another_extreme 
                                                        + self.distances.get_(new_vertex, another_extreme),
                                 path_to_another_extreme = self.path_to_rightmost,
                                 distance_to_another_extreme = self.distance_to_rightmost,
                                 distances = self.distances)
        return result

    def add_to_both(self):
        new_vertex = self.path_to_rightmost[-1] + 1
        another_extreme = self.path_to_another_extreme[-1]
        result = TwoPartialPaths(path_to_rightmost = self.path_to_another_extreme + [new_vertex],
                                 distance_to_rightmost = self.distance_to_another_extreme 
                                    + self.distances.get_(new_vertex, another_extreme),
                                 path_to_another_extreme = self.path_to_rightmost + [new_vertex],
                                 distance_to_another_extreme = self.distance_to_rightmost 
                                    + self.distances.get_(new_vertex, new_vertex-1),
                                 distances = self.distances)
        return result

    def get_total_distance(self):
        return self.distance_to_rightmost + self.distance_to_another_extreme

# solve it
def find_bitonic_path(vertice):    
    # initialise the distances
    distances = Distances(vertice = vertice)  

    # initialisation for 2 leftmost vertice
    shortest_paths_given_ends = [TwoPartialPaths(path_to_rightmost = [0, 1], 
                                                 distance_to_rightmost = distances.get_(1, 0), 
                                                 path_to_another_extreme = [0], 
                                                 distance_to_another_extreme = 0.,
                                                 distances = distances)]         

    # do other vertice, except the last one
    for _ in xrange(len(vertice) - 3):
        # find the last element, when we add to another extreme
        best_last = shortest_paths_given_ends[0].add_to_another()
        for pspge in shortest_paths_given_ends[1:]:
            challenger = pspge.add_to_another()
            if challenger.get_total_distance() < best_last.get_total_distance():
                best_last = challenger 
        # handle simple cases, when we add to the rightmost extreme,
        # and the other extreme does not change
        shortest_paths_given_ends = [
            spge.add_to_rightmost() for spge in shortest_paths_given_ends] + [best_last]

    # do the rightmost vertex
    result = shortest_paths_given_ends[0].add_to_both()    
    for spge in shortest_paths_given_ends[1:]:
        challenger = spge.add_to_both()
        if challenger.get_total_distance() < result.get_total_distance():
            result = challenger

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    vertice = [[0,0], [3,4], [7,0], [10,4]] # [(random.random(), random.random()) for _ in xrange(4)]
    for v in vertice:
        print v
    result = find_bitonic_path(vertice = vertice)
    result.print_out()
```

Comment: Perhaps I missed it, but I am surprised you did not implement lazy loading for your distances matrix. Relatedly, this class might be best as a singleton class to make good and sure you don't compute those distances extra times.

Comment: @sunny: I guess potentially one might want to have several different sets of distances for other applications, this is why I avoided having it as a  static field; I guess this is also the reason why singleton should be avoided. Would you agree?

Comment: @sunny: no lazy evaluation, but, since each edge is studies only one time, I do not need to store it. Good point!

Comment: Cool beans. I'm going to look at this some more tmw b/c I'd like to learn more about this algorithm. Hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 4):

The `print_out` function in your class `TwoPartialPaths` should be changed to a [magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html), in this case, `__str__`. Here's how you could do that:

```
def __str__(self):
    return (
        "path 1 is " + self.path_to_rightmost +
        "\ndistance 1 is " + self.distance_to_rightmost +
        "\npath 2 is " + self.path_to_another_extreme +
        "\ndistance 2 is " + self.distance_to_another_extreme +
        "\noverall distance " + self.get_total_distance()
    )
```

We can make this method much better though. Rather than using string concatenation, we can use the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) method. We can also get rid of those extra `+`'es at the end of each line as well, using implicit concatenation. Using `str.format`, and implicit concatenation, `TwoPartialPaths.__str__` becomes this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return (
        "path 1 is {}".format(self.path_to_rightmost)
        "\ndistance 1 is {}".format(self.distance_to_rightmost)
        "\npath 2 is {}".format(self.path_to_another_extreme)
        "\ndistance 2 is {}".format(self.distance_to_another_extreme)
        "\noverall distance {}".format(self.get_total_distance())
    )
```

But that's not all, we can shorten this two one line, by combining all of these `str.format`s into one, and formatting one long string.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "path 1 is {}\ndistance 1 is {}\npath 2 is {}\ndistance 2 is {}\noverall distance is {}".\ format(
        self.path_to_rightmost, self.distance_to_rightmost, self.path_to_another_extreme, self.distance_to_another_extreme, self.get_total_distance()
    )
```

After doing all this, all you have to do to output data about a `TwoPartialPaths` class instance is this:

```
tpp = TwoPartialPaths( ... )
print tpp
```

---

In any version of Python 2.x, when you create classes, you need to have them explicitly inherit from `object`, like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
```

If you're using Python 3.x or higher, you can just type them like this:

```
class MyClass:
    ...
```

---

Finally, I'm noticing that you're missing whitespace in a few areas. For example, this:

```
(vertice[i][0]-vertice[j][0])**2 + (vertice[i][1]-vertice[j][1])**2
```

Should be expanded to this:

```
(vertice[i][0] - vertice[j][0]) ** 2 + (vertice[i][1] - vertice[j][1]) ** 2
```

Adding whitespace around operators generally increases the readability of your code, and if it voilates the 80 characters per line limit, you can always use the line break character, `\`, to continue the line's contents on a separate line.

Comment: Thanks! I believe `format()` takes arbitrary number of arguments, so it is possible to call it only once, with 5 arguments, this makes the code shorter.

Comment: @YuliaV Hmm, good point. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: "path 1 is {}\ndistance 1 is {}\npath 2 is {}\ndistance 2 is {}\noverall distance is {}".\
            format(self.path_to_rightmost, self.distance_to_rightmost, self.path_to_another_extreme,
                   self.distance_to_another_extreme, self.get_total_distance())

Comment: @YuliaV Added into answer.

Comment: As someone still learning python, this new string `format` thing has me puzzled.  Python is supposed to emphasize readability, but to my eyes the string concatenation with `+` is far more readable than all this `{}` and `format` business.  Plus many python tutorials (e.g. codecademy) still introduce string concetenation early.  I'm not doubting that `format` is better -- it's probably mentioned in >50% of all python posts on CR.SE -- but where is a good introduction to _why_?

Comment: @CurtF. You can have a good layout of what the string looks like before it's formatted. For example: `"SELECT {row} FROM {table};".format(row=..., table=...)` is much clearer than `"SELECT " + row + " FROM " + table" + ";"`. In addition, you don't need to have those ugly looking spaces.

Comment: @CurtF. `str.format` also allows for the user to do things that would be rather clunky with concatenation. For example: `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; print "{0}{1}{2}{2}{5}{3}{2}".format(a)` rather than `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; print str(a[0]) + str(a[1]) + str(a[2]) + str(a[2]) + str(a[5]) + str(a[3]) + str(a[2])`. Which one is clearer now?

Answer (score 2):

I looked over your newer code. I have not implemented the bitonic algorithm myself, so apologies in advance if anything below is based on a misunderstanding of the algo or of your code. Thanks for showing me this new algo.

**Structure**

- **Why don't you just start with a sorted list of points?** Your code is tricky to read because you are often going back and forth between the sorted and unsorted list of points, even though so far as I understand from the algorithm, the unsorted version is irrelevant.
- **Why aren't you using dynamic programming (or did I miss it)?** This problem is known to lend itself to dynamic programming, but I don't see it used in your code. For example, in `TwoPartialPaths.add_to_another` why don't you memo-ize the result of `self.vertice.get_distance(another_extreme, next_vertex)`? Are you sure you won't be calling that function on that exact same set of values again?

**Tricky Names**

- **Your variable names are often far longer than they need to be without adding clarity.** For example, instead of `distance_to_rightmost` and `distance_to_another_extremum` why not use `right_path` and `left_path`? From what I read up on this algorithm, most people seem to talk about them as the right and left directional paths, or call them `path_top` and `path_bottom` if you're visualizing a 2d layout. What I'm saying is your longer names don't add clarity.
- **You are inconsistent about creating local variables in your functions for single use**. I would recommend, for example, in `Vertice.__init__` naming a variable for `len(vertice_coordinates)` rather than calling this function 3 times, as you do. On the other hand, I wonder whether you need to have a `result` variable in the following `TwoPartialPaths` member functions: `add_to_righmost, add_to_another, and add_to_both`. Why not just return the result of the functional call directly? The `result` variable doesn't enhance readability.
- **Why `Vertice` as a class name instead of `vertex`?** This was confusing and a bit wordier than necessary.

**Program Consistency**

- **You call `self.vertice.get_distance(another_extreme, next_vertex)` within `add_to_another` but I didn't notice any other instances of nested function calls.** I have no problem with nested function calls, but since you only do it once, interspersed with lots of very long parameter names, this is easy for a reader to miss. I would move this to a local variable in the function and then just pass the local variable, in the interests of readability and consistency of style within your program.

Comment: thank you, I have added comments to your comments to my question!